# React profile pic with rotating border issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, rxjs

So I am trying to do something like this YouTube CV profile pic tutorial in React: https://youtu.be/VjiWpGR82t0.

When I try to put an image, the entire image spins but I want just the border to spin instead.

And when it deform to show a little bit of the image like in the video.

I changed it to 1sec interval so it spins a lot faster for testing purposes.

### This is my App.js:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="circle rotating"><div className="circle2"></div></div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### This is my index.css:

````css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
    color: #fff;
  }

  .circle{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-top-left-radius : 48%;
    border-top-right-radius : 48%;
    border-bottom-left-radius : 48%;
    border-bottom-right-radius : 48%;
    background: #27a9e1;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  .circle2{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-top-left-radius : 50%;
    border-top-right-radius : 50%;
    border-bottom-left-radius : 50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius : 65%;
    background: #27a9e1;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  @keyframes rotating {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.rotating {
    animation: rotating 1s linear infinite;
}
```
Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?
````

Answer (score -1):

Try this: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/circle-profile-pic-border-rotate) code:

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="circle rotating">
        <div className="circle2"></div>
      </div>
      <img
        src="https://cdn.vectorstock.com/i/preview-1x/20/76/man-avatar-profile-vector-21372076.jpg"
        alt="profile-pic"
        className="profile-pic"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.circle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 65%;
  background: #27a9e1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.circle2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 65%;
  background: transparent;
}

.profile-pic {
  width: 198px;
  height: 198px;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg); /* Counter-rotate the image */
}

@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.rotating {
  animation: rotating 1s linear infinite;
}
```